# Corda CorDapps only on a subset of nodes

Tags: blockchain, nodes, corda, corda-dlt

I am relatively new to Corda and stumbled upon a question that I am not able to find a clear answer to.
In my understanding a CorDapp is the entirety of Contract,State and Flows regarding a specific Use-Case.

Would it be possible to have different CorDapps running on different nodes?

For example in a network with 3 participants A,B and C where A&B need to interact with eachother and B&C need to interact with eachother with a different Use-Case. Can A&B have the CorDapp for their Use-Case running without C having it installed on their ledger?
Basically the question is, if all nodes on the network have to share all CorDapps no matter if they interact with eachother or not.

Thanks in advance
Florian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is definitly possible and one of the main advantages, from my perspective, of a Corda. In Corda, nodes only need to have the CorDapps relevant to the them. In your example, A and B would only need to have the CorDapp for `payables` product, as an example, and C would only have `receivables` product.
In addition, there is also a possibility for all CorDapps to be installed on a single node, but access to them can be managed on the Client Service application (e.g. Spring Service that communicates with Corda Node)